# Compare a field within the same file

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I have a file with the following data

file name: sample.rcv.gz

data:

```
title|currentDate|numberOfLines|
a|ID99900|Paul|Lee|
b|ID99900|New York|7890654|
c|ID99900|Driver|1232423|
a|ID99901|Jim|foo|
b|ID99901|California|1265789|
c|ID99901|Officer|3332424|
a|ID99902|Jean|duval|
b|ID99902|California|9865789|
c|ID99902|Officer|5552424|
a|ID99900|Philips|Chand|
b|ID99900|Delhi|6310654|
c|ID99900|Teacher|7653423|
```

where a,b,c are table name.

How to find duplicate ID for the same table?

thanks

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can make it:

```
$ awk -F"|" 'a[$1,$2]++' file
a|ID99900|Philips|Chand|
b|ID99900|Delhi|6310654|
c|ID99900|Teacher|7653423|
```

#### Update

> Can you tell me how to stop the shell if duplicate data are found? to
>   stop/exit the process when the 1st duplicate is found and also echo a
>   message with the duplicate ID and the table name.
>
> Example: Duplicate data: ID99900 in table A

This can make it:

```
$ awk -F"|" 'a[$1,$2]++ {print "Duplicate data: "$2" in table "$1; exit}' file
Duplicate data: ID99900 in table a
```

Comment: can you tell me how to stop the shell if duplicate data are found?

Comment: What do you exactly mean? To stop when the first duplicate data is found?

Comment: ya, to stop/exit the process when the 1st duplicate is found and also echo a message with the duplicate ID and the table name. Example: Duplicate data: ID99900 in table A

Comment: another question, suppose the Shell is in path /aaa/bbb/ccc/Shell.sh and the rcv file is in /ccc/ddd/sample.rcv.gz. the filename in the command awk should be sample.rcv.gz  or /ccc/ddd/sample.rcv.gz because they are in different folders?

Comment: If you have a new question, please start a new one. I posted some code that might be helpful for you although you did not show any of your approaches. Now you'd better mark this question as solved and open a new one showing part of what you've already done.

Comment: @godsmAsh oh wait, now I see you updated your previous comment and it is related to this question. Sorry. To be sure, add the full path of the file, that is do `awk .... <things> .... /ccc/ddd/sample.rcv.gz`

Comment: thanks again for the confirmation and your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"|" 'NR!=1{if($1$2 in a)print "Duplicate:",$1,$2;else a[$1$2]}' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
title|currentDate|numberOfLines|
a|ID99900|Paul|Lee|
b|ID99900|New York|7890654|
c|ID99900|Driver|1232423|
a|ID99901|Jim|foo|
b|ID99901|California|1265789|
c|ID99901|Officer|3332424|
a|ID99902|Jean|duval|
b|ID99902|California|9865789|
c|ID99902|Officer|5552424|
a|ID99900|Philips|Chand|
b|ID99900|Delhi|6310654|
c|ID99900|Teacher|7653423|
> awk -F"|" 'NR!=1{if($1$2 in a)print "Duplicate:",$1,$2;else a[$1$2]}' temp
Duplicate: a ID99900
Duplicate: b ID99900
Duplicate: c ID99900
>
```

Comment: will $1 increment to table B if no duplicate was found in table A?